# Using iif eval to test for DATE value

Tags: asp.net

I am trying  to display the contents of a label based on whether the date on the document is greater than or equivalent to 1 January 2013.

I did this and tried changing this into various ways but doesn't seem to be giving the results I want.

```
<asp:Label ID="RefLabel" runat="server" Text='ކޮޕީ:' 
     Visible='<%# IIf(Eval("DateGregEng", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") = "1 January 2013", "False","True") %>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: are you using it inside gridview??

Answer (score 1):

try using  `DataBinder.Eval` rather than `Eval`.

```
<asp:Label ID="RefLabel" runat="server" Text='ކޮޕީ:' 
     Visible='<%# IIf(DataBinder.Eval("DateGregEng", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") = "1 January 2013", "False","True") %>'>
</asp:Label>
```